# Toolkit and paintComponent not working together

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

To initialize my image, I have:

```
imageWater = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("water5.gif");
```

In my paintComponent() method, I have something like this:

```
g.drawImage(imageWater, 50, 50, 50, 50, this);
```

However, if I change the reference of imageWater to a different file than water5.gif, say, water6.gif, nothing else in the paintComponent() method works, even those that are completely unrelated to imageWater. I have tried changing both variables and references, and nothing works until I replace that exact file in that exact place. I do not understand why this is occurring.

My theory is that the thread.sleep I've been using does not perform well with paintComponent (or any gui in general) and I have merely been getting lucky for whatever reason before. I hesitate to test this because I have many thread.sleep() throughout the document and have no idea how to substitute them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"My theory is that the thread.sleep I've been using does not perform well with paintComponent (or any gui in general"* would be correct.

The fact hat you've not provided us with a working example to look at makes it difficult to understand what it is your are doing or what it is your trying to achieve.

Yu might like it have a look at

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For more information on the topic and possible solutions

Comment: I apologize, I initially thought to post a simplified version of my code as reference because my code is a thousand lines long, but I realized I didn't really understand much of it myself (a sign of bad programming). I will add a more detailed description of the methods inside of my class and what they are intended to do.

Comment: On the other hand, I believe swing timers were what I was looking for. Thank you. I was looking into the util timers and had difficulty using them.

Comment: *"a sign of bad programming"* - only if you weren't intended in learning. To me, it's a sign of inexperience ;)